# Addition doesn't work in rows in reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

why addition doesn't work in my reactive. i tried subtraction and multiplication and it all works. addition in this combines the number. does it make it a string?
Code is here [Plunkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xm0LduSK7GEYCg3n3HV1?p=preview)

```
 <td>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly formControlName="itemamt" [ngModel]="itemrow.get('itemqty').value + itemrow.get('itemrate').value">
 </td>
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more

Comment: Its working perfectly fine

Comment: @VivekDoshi. The subtraction and multiplications does work But the addition doesnt work

Comment: @GraySingh , I have gone through the plunker and its giving correct answer fo all

Comment: @VivekDoshi. change this into <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly formControlName="itemamt" [ngModel]="itemrow.get('itemqty').value + itemrow.get('itemrate').value">. Then type 1 and 2. The result will be 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any value from an HTML input is automatically string.

Issue is same as explained by @Sajeetharan , but the solution he suggested can't be done on template side .

**Simple Solution :**

Is just change the input type `text` to `number`

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="itemqty">
```

**[WORKING PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/C3Km76I5Mqvi4bckEgMh?p=preview)**

Comment: @Joseph , Okay let me check

Comment: How is it Vivek? Is it okay?

Comment: Its ok. Thank you

Comment: @Joseph , please post on the related question :)

Answer (score 0):

Any value from an HTML input is automatically **`string`**. To resolve this, you must cast/convert your input value to a **`number`**.

whereas the other arithmetic operators **`/ * -`** will perform a toNumber conversion on the string(s).

A quick way to convert a string to a number is to use the unary **`+`** operator.